# Navigation Timeout Exceeded with react-snap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am having React App and I'm trying re-render everything in my local using react-snap but it seems to be timing out and I have attached below image for reference.

**Note : My application has around 5 reactc routes with Firebase connectivity to fetch the data.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the react-snap version to 1.10.0 fixed it for me.